# Grub can't boot on SATA hard disk connected on extra PCIe card (Driver problem ?)

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, hard-drive

My configuration is the following :

- a SATA hard disk on motherboard, recognised by the BIOS
- a SATA hard disk on an extra PCIe-SATA board (Asmedia chipset) not recognised by BIOS

I am not sure it could work but : I would like to use the disk on the motherboard to install GRUB on it and make it boot on the PCIe-SATA hard disk.

I tried to install Debian and Ubuntu and both detect the PCIe-SATA hard disk and are ok to install on any of it. However GRUB can't make boot the PCIe-SATA hard disk.

Once booted, ubuntu says :

```
$ lspci | grep -i sata
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
23:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 0622 (rev 01)
```

so it seems the card and driver are detected. The PCIe-SATA hard disk can then be seen :

```
$sudo fdisk -l

Disque /dev/sda : 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 octets, 1953525168 secteurs
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x005ad4f9

Périphérique Amorçage      Début        Fin   Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sda1    *              2048     104447     102400    50M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2                 104448 1952469024 1952364577   931G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3             1952471040 1953519615    1048576   512M 27 TFS WinRE masquée


Disque /dev/sdc : 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs
Disk model: WDC WD5000LPLX-7
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x1b4d2ba4

Périphérique Amorçage   Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sdc1    *           2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sdc2             1052670 976771071 975718402 465,3G  5 Étendue
/dev/sdc5             1052672 976771071 975718400 465,3G 83 Linux
```

so sda is seen as the hard drive connected on the PCIe-SATA and sdc is the motherboard connected hard disk.

When I run GRUB on the PCIe-SATA hard disk, I get the following :

```
no such device : 3AE0E5C5E0E58809
```

If I run the GRUB CLI, I try :

```
insmod lspci
```

and I get at address 23:00.0 :

```
23:00.0 1b21:0622 [0106] SATA Controller [PI 01]
```

I don't know if that means that the controller is managed or not by GRUB (or can it be ?)

trying a ls in grub lead to the detection of a single hard disk :

```
grub> ls
(proc) (hd0) (hd0.msdos5) (hd0.msdos1)
```

Is there something I can do so that GRUB may boot on my other hard disk ?

Best regards,
Mike

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what GRUB can do but I guess it could load a linux kernel with a driver to then start the windows partition. But it seems it is not the case. Perhaps can a small linux kernel start windows ?

Comment: The source driver of the device is on a eSATA connection that is detected by the BIOS.
There are two hard disks : one on the eSATA of the motherboard (but slow) and one on a PCIe/eSATA card (much quicker). The GRUB is on the slow eSATA connection (recognized by the bios) and I want to boot on the PCIe/eSATA one. I hoped installing GRUB would bypass the BIOS. It seems not.